# Detection and tracking of a moving car

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am doing a project on "car tracking". I am trying to develop a code that will run in real time and will be able to detect car approaching a junction. Ι subtract two consecutive frames and then `thresholding.Implement` morphological closing  and then I find the moving car. My problem is that I can not detect dark cars. I would realy I appreciate if you give me some guidelines to successfully finish this project.

```
%Code for tracking
vid = videoinput('winvideo', '1', 'RGB24_640x360');
 set(vid,'ReturnedColorSpace','rgb');
 set(vid,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
src = getselectedsource(vid);
src.FocusMode = 'manual';
%pause(0.02);
[i rect]=imcrop(getsnapshot(vid));
 set(vid,'ROIPosition',rect);

 h = fspecial('gaussian',[3,3],5);
%structial element

se90 = strel('line',5, 90);
se0 = strel('line', 5, 0);
ss=strel('diamond',10);
 var=3;
 start(vid);

 for i=1:500
     tic
     im1= getsnapshot(vid);
     imrgb=im1;
     im1=im1(:,:,1);
     if var==3

     im2= getsnapshot(vid);
     im2=im2(:,:,1);
     im2=imfilter(im2,h);
    var=0;
     end
     %-------------------------------------------------

        if 1
         m1=imfilter(im1,h); 

     %   c2=im2-im1

    %cbw=im2bw(c2);
    %allagi stin evais8isia tou threshold
    cbw=imsub(im1,im2,14,h);


     end
     cbw1 = imerode(cbw, [se90,se0]); %sistoli
    % cbw1 = imerode(cbw1, [se901,se01]);
    %diastoli 
    cbw1= imdilate(cbw1,ss); 
    %fill holes
    cbw2= imfill(cbw1, 'holes');
    cbw2= imfill(cbw2, 'holes');
    if 1
    cbw3 = imerode(cbw2, [se90 se0]); %sistoli
    cbw3 = imerode(cbw3, [se90 se0]); %sistoli
    cbw3 = imerode(cbw3, [se90 se0]); %sistoli
    cbw3 = imerode(cbw3, [se90 se0]);
    cbw3= imfill(cbw3, 'holes'); %fill hole
    end

    if 1
    %Boundary box
    s = regionprops(cbw3, 'BoundingBox');
    if ~isempty(s)
    cd = s.BoundingBox;
    end
    figure(1),
    %imshow(cbw3);
    imshow(imrgb)
    hold on;
    if ~isempty(s)
    rectangle('Position',[cd(:,1) cd(:,2) cd(:,3) cd(:,4)],'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor','b');
    end
    hold('off');
    end
    %empty ram
    flushdata(vid)
    var=var+1;
    toc 
 end
 stop(vid)
```

Comment: A simple thresholding and some morphological operations are usually not enough to provide good results in all but the best conditions. You usually need more advanced computer vision tools to achieve more reliable results, I suggest doing some research in the topic "segmentation", and choose what method would seem to fit your problem the best.

Comment: A agree with vsz. But if you want to apply this to dark car segmentation, what about negating the image and running the same approach?

Comment: @petrichor I guess the problem is due to the fact that the dark cars are too similar in color to the road. Negating would not solve the problem in that case. Else, I agree with vsz too.

Comment: I ran into this same problem a while ago. There are two scenarios that I imagine you could be in: stationary or mobile camera. The stationary camera case is simple as rather than image recognition techniques, you should be using motion-based detection. This will also improve your light car detection. If your camera is mobile, you should add in a mathematical filter that will "transform out" the effects of camera motion on stationary objects. In my project I used an ANN

Answer (score 1):

Check out [vision.ForegroundDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.foregrounddetectorclass.html) in the Computer Vision System Toolbox, and the following [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html).